# how to restrict perl bots through php when perl changes useragent name

Tags: php, perl, user-agent

Let's say we have the following perl script

```
    use LWP;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use LWP::UserAgent;


    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->agent('NokiaN97i/SymbianOS/9.1 Series60/3.0');

    my $response = $ua->get('http://myhost.com');

    if ($response->is_success) print $response->decoded_content;
    else die $response->status_line;
```

which just connects to myhost.com/index.php page and prints its content.
In index.php file I have

```
 file_put_contents('agent.txt', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], FILE_APPEND);
```

line. Now user agent string does not contain "libwww-perl". How can I recognize perl bot and restrict it?

Comment: Might be worth trying `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_USER_AGENT']` too

Comment: Thank you Dale, I tried to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_USER_AGENT'] but it prints nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, the USER_AGENT string while being the only factor that helps you identify the client's "browser" is also basically user input. If they change it - there's nothing that you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you Narf. So you say that there is no chance to recognize real user agent? For example if I want to restrict all browsers except mobile ones,  is there the way to do that?

Comment: No, there isn't, as even browsers make it possible to change the useragent.

Comment: @Paramore No. You can still use the user agent string to determine e.g. if you should serve a mobile or a desktop version of a website. But it will not be 100% reliable and you deffinately shouldn't use it for enforcing restrictions.